# Extract data from HTML using java

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I want to extract data HTML using Java. I tried using Jsoup but so far I'm unable to extract the correct data. Here is the HTML code snippet from which I'm trying to extract the data.

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="listen_880966" onclick="MP3PREVIEWPLAYER.showHiddePlayer(880966, 'http://mksh.free.fr/' + 'lol/mp3/Paint_It_Black/18_the_black_dahlia_murder_-_paint_it_black_(rolling_stones)-bfhmp3.mp3')" title="Listen Paint it Black    The Black Dahlia Murder   Great Metal Covers 36" class="button button-s button-1 listen "   >
```

I want the link ("http://mksh.free.fr/' + 'lol/mp3/Paint_It_Black/18_the_black_dahlia_murder_-_paint_it_black_(rolling_stones)-bfhmp3.mp3") and the title to be extracted into different variables. It would be really helpful if a sample code is provided along with the answer.

Comment: First of all, can you show us what you tried?h

Answer (score 4):

You can use Regular Expressions to parse out the section you want.  Then you can use something like string.split(delimiter) to extract out the specific info.  See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/string-split-in-java) for info on the string.split() method

```
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
            String mydata = "<a href=\"javascript:;\" id=\"listen_880966\" onclick=\"MP3PREVIEWPLAYER.showHiddePlayer(880966, 'http://mksh.free.fr/' + 'lol/mp3/Paint_It_Black/18_the_black_dahlia_murder_-_paint_it_black_(rolling_stones)-bfhmp3.mp3')\" title=\"Listen Paint it Black    The Black Dahlia Murder   Great Metal Covers 36\" class=\"button button-s button-1 listen \"   >";
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("'http://mksh.free.fr/'\\s.\\s'[\\(\\).A-Za-z0-9/_-]+'");
            Pattern title = Pattern.compile("title=\\\"[A-Za-z0-9\\s]+\\\"");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
            if (matcher.find())
            {
                System.out.println(matcher.group(0));

            }
            matcher = title.matcher(mydata);
            if(matcher.find())
                System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
    }
}
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/HXaHxB)